# How to include an "Archive" folder in every new folder I create?

Tags: python, windows, command-line

As part of my workflow, every folder I create, I also need to create an "Archive" folder within that new folder for version control. Is there a way to automate this process? This is on Windows 10.

Comment: Is the bash label a mistake?

Comment: is it that you want to do this in python script or from command line or what?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to start. I know I have access to Python and Command Line.